# Typo3 Static Info Tables get rid of onchange event

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

I´m using tt_products 2.8.1 and static_info_tables 6.3.6 together with Typo3 6.2.17.

On my checkout page I have a country drop down which looks like:

```
<select size="1" id="field_personinfo_country_code" name="recs[personinfo][country_code]" onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

I need to get rid of the onchange event.

```
onchange="this.form.submit();"
```

Following this instruction: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/static_info_tables/Configuration/TyposcriptReference/Index.html

```
plugin.tx_staticinfotables_pi1.onChangeAttribute = ''
```

In my template constants should do it. Unfortunately this does not change anything. Helpful for any Ideas how to strip this.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is missing in tt_products 2.8.1.
You must change the line 499 in file view/class.tx_ttproducts_info_view.php:

```
$markerArray['###PERSON_COUNTRY_CODE###'] =
    $staticInfo->buildStaticInfoSelector(
        'COUNTRIES',
        'recs[personinfo][country_code]',
        '',
        $countryCodeArray['billing'],
        '',
        '',
        'field_personinfo_country_code'
    );
```

Parameter number 6 is the onChangeCountryAttribute. This is a setup value in tt_products 2.12.0: "this.form.submit();" by default.

As an alternative you can also set the object $staticInfo to your own object. Extension div2007 has a method:

```
    $staticInfo = \JambageCom\Div2007\Utility\StaticInfoTablesUtility::getStaticInfo();
```

Comment: Thanks Franz Holzinger, this was good help the second time ;) Maybe you have a hint for me how to hide countries from the tt_products country select as well?

Comment: See the chapter 6.1.2 of the book [Der TYPO3-Webshop](http://www.fosdoc.de/downloads/OSP_typo3webshop.pdf) page 134. **where.static_countries = cn_short_local = 'Deutschland'** . You can use any field of the table static_countries to build the where condition of the country selector.